# Reversibility of Ageing

Tags: irreversible-damage, age

Can somebody pinpoint exactly why a living organism ages towards death? And why is ageing irreversible in almost all organisms?

Comment: Please do some research on the matter first and include what you found into the question body. For starters, reversible changes are commonly not understood under the term "aging" to begin with since its definition often includes that what happens is irreversible.

Comment: This question is easily answered with a simple google search.